# how to prevent reading while writing?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have deployed a network application for my client to post their data to my spreadsheet.

Each time they post a set of data, my applicantion will write them into the last row of my sheet.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
var index = sheet.getlastRow();
sheet.getRange(index,1,1,10).setValues(data);
```

The problem is when more than one people use this applicant at a moment,it may get the same lastRow,and some data will missing.

***like this :***

**1. A read lastRow n**

**2. B read lastRow n (before A write)**

**3. A write at row n**

**4. B write at row n (and A's data missing)**

Is their any solution to fix this problem?

Or is their any way to prevent reading while another is reading?

Comment: This is what [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/) is for. Use it.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I need! @CrazyIvan

Comment: Try to use [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents](http://appendRow) comand it add new row in spreadsheet instead of overwrite

Comment: Thanks! This is really a simply way to fix this problem. @Davagaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to use **[appendrow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addviewersemailaddresses)** function.

Another way is to use **[Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/)**, and this way is more flexible and easy to extend.